# Changing function to Maybe function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, monads

Is it possible to write a function which takes a function like `(Something -> Something)`, and returns it, but with a type `(Maybe Something -> Maybe Something)`?

e.g.:

```
f :: Point -> Point
f x = [some code goes here]

makeItMaybe :: (Point -> Point) -> (Maybe Point -> Maybe Point)
makeItMaybe x = ???
```

I know it has something to do with Monads and Applicatives, but can't really figure out how. I played around a bit with `<*>` and `<$>`, but didn't get anywhere.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `makeItMaybe = fmap`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for `fmap`, which has type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. If you replace `f` by `Maybe` (since `Maybe` is a functor) and put the parenthesis un the right place you get `(a -> b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)`. You were in the right direction with `(<$>)`, which is just an alias for `fmap`.

So we have `makeItMaybe f x = fmap f x` or, more simply, `makeItMaybe = fmap`.

Answer (score 3):

The function you want is `fmap`:

```
makeItMaybe = fmap
```

`fmap` is defined by the `Functor` typeclass:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`Maybe` has a functor instance so `fmap` specialised to `Maybe` has type

```
(a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

Comment: You're using `f` as a free variable in your answer, but in the question `f` is one of the parameters to `makeItMaybe`, so a more accurate answer is `makeItMaybe = fmap`, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: @amalloy - Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This functions satisfies the signature, but I don't know if it is what you want:

```
makeItMaybe :: (a -> a) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe a)
makeItMaybe f (Just x) = Just (f x)
makeItMaybe f Nothing  = Nothing
```

As  @baxbaxwalanuksiwe and @Lee pointed out, it is `fmap` instance of `Maybe` from the `Functor` typeclass.

Comment: What happens if the second argument is `Nothing` ? You could indeed define `makeItMaybe f Nothing = Nothing`, but then it's juste a definition of `fmap`.